# Update notification upon login

Tags: debian

How do I configure Debian Wheezy to show available updates upon login on a virtual console? When I used Ubuntu it was setup by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative is to use Apticron which sends an email (typically to user@localhost) whenever updates are available.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu, this is provided by a package called `update-motd` as explained over at [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105689/how-is-etc-motd-updated)

It is possible to replicate this on Debian and Nick Charlton has a good article on it [here](https://nickcharlton.net/posts/debian-ubuntu-dynamic-motd.html). It's a bit long to copy/paste into U&L though, hence the link.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The solution is a bit too complicated for my taste though - I thought it was just an `apt-get install` away. Maybe Nick should turn his solution into a deb package.

Comment: I believe all you'd need to do is create the directory (`/etc/update-motd.d`) and copy/paste the `20-updates` file from the article into it.